# Localstorage not storing data

Tags: jquery, html, local-storage, jstorage

I have a method as follows and failing to store the data to local storage.

```
var get = function(setting) {
    var s = jqueryAjaxGetSettings(setting,true);
    if(!s.disableLoader){
        var promise = startLoading(s.loaderName,s.largeLoader);
        promise.then(function(){$.ajax(s)}, function(){$.ajax(s)});
    } else
        $.ajax(s);
};

       var countries = $.jStorage.get("app.common/parameters/countries");

        var countrySelector = {
            app : 'app',
            service : '/parameters/countries',
            disableLoader:true,
            cache: true,
            cdn: true,
            callback : function(response) {
                countries = response.data;
                $.jStorage.set("app/parameters/countries ", countries , {TTL: 3600000});
                self.setItemList();
            }
        }

        if(!countries ){
            ajaxWrapper.get(countrySelector);
        } else {
            self.setItemList();
        }
```

I have similar methods and they are storing the data fine.

What would be the case here?

Comment: Are you sure the `callback` function was fired? Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: I see the call being made to app/parameters/items in Network but i have break point there which is never hit. by the way I am using akamai here.

Comment: I'm not so sure how it's related to the `network` tab... localstore is local (in the client, not in the server). Not related to the network in any way. If you have a breakpoint that never hit - this part of the code will never run. Who is suppose to fire the `callback` function?

Comment: Updated the question. hope it is more clear now.

Comment: ok, so now the question is what is `ajaxWrapper`? :)

Comment: well I knew it. updated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126756/discussion-between-dekel-and-darthvader).